# Count instances on a table

Tags: relational-algebra

If I have a table with duplicate instances how can I count if I don't have a count function?

All I have is select, project, union, difference, product, intersect, njoin. I am using [WinRDBI](https://winrdbi.asu.edu/).

Table looks like this:

**Children**

```
ID| NAME|
A | 'alice'
A | 'jon'
A | 'alex'
B | 'joe'
B | 'mary'
C | 'amy'
```

**Parent**

```
    ID| NAME|
    A | 'Smith'
    B | 'Johnson'
    C | 'Meyer'
```

I want to know how what parent has two children.

Comment: What output are you trying to produce?

Comment: I want to know how what parent has two children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the difference operator and the fact that `(n*n)-n = n` is true only for n = 2 when n > 0.

1. For each parent, create a cross product of their Children [call this "C"] with itself by renaming second copy of Children [call this "C1"]. Let's call this "CxC1"
2. If (((select attributes of C from CxC1) - C) = C) then the parent has exactly 2 children [1]

[1] Assuming referential integrity such that a parent cannot have zero children.